# How to custom color in custom_date_range_picker on showCustomDateRangePicker

Tags: flutter, widget

How to add a custom color in `custom_date_range_picker` on `showCustomDateRangePicker`.
I want to set the color in the button and theme.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
              TextButton.icon(
            onPressed: () { 
              showCustomDateRangePicker(      
                context,
                dismissible: true,
                maximumDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 30)),
                minimumDate: DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1500)),
                onApplyClick: (start, end) {
                  scanHistoryCubit.onFilterScanHistoryDateRange(start, end);
                },
                onCancelClick: () {},
              );
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month_outlined, color: Colors.white),
            label:
                BlocSelector<ScanHistoryCubit, ScanHistoryState, String?>(
              selector: (state) => state.filterDate,
              builder: (context, filterName) {
                return Text('${filterName ?? context.getLocale?.dateLabel}',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Palette.lowWhite,
                    ));
              },
            ),
          ),
```